# How to solve jquery ui / firefox bug in state button with removeClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, firefox

I limit the number of checked checkboxes but style was not correct on firefox.
Actually theres a bug on firefox with state button, see this exemple on firefox,
When you doubleclick on a button, state isnot update well if lengh > 3 (in this case ) , so i try to remove class of ui state but it doesn't work , is someone got a solution ?!

http://jsfiddle.net/mbAwC/22/

```
$('.limit :checkbox').change(function () {
    var $cs=$(this).closest('.limit').find(':checkbox:checked');
    if ($cs.length > 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false).removeClass("ui-state-active ui-state-hover ui-state-focus").button('refresh');
```

regards
jess

Comment: This is a weird bug, cause it happens on the double-click. That is why your code does not work, because on the double click no "change" event occurs. So you cannot change the status and remove the classes in "onchange"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird bug, cause it happens on the double-click event. That is why your code does not work, because on the double click no "change" event occurs. So you cannot change the status and remove the classes in "onchange".
As a fix for this funny issue I tried to add sth like this:

```
$('.limit label').dblclick(function () {
     if (!$(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active ui-state-hover ui-state-focus ");
    }
});
```

This handles the weird double click and removes the styles if they where applied incorrectly on a checkbox which is not checked.